# Proving determinants is independent of theta

Tags: trigonometry, determinant

$$A=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin\left(\theta+\alpha\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\alpha\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\theta+\beta\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\beta\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\theta+\gamma\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\gamma\right) & 1
\end{array}\right|$$

My approach is to subtract row 1 from row 2 and row 3 then open the determinant. The problem with this approach is it involves way too much calculation. I tried to take something common but nothing comes to mind. Can somebody give me a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I've rewritten it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @BLuthra Are you allowed / do you know calculus? The derivative of $A$ wrt $\theta$ is visibly zero

Comment: The determinant gives (up to a scalar multiple) the volume of a tetrahedron with vertices $(\cos(\alpha+\theta), \sin(\alpha+\theta), 1)$, etc, and the origin. Rotating the tetrahedron through angle $\theta$ about the $z$ axis moves the non-origin vertices to $(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha, 1)$, etc. Clearly, the volume doesn't change, but the determinant is freed of $\theta$.

Comment: @peterag we have to prove determinant is independent of theta not equal to zero

Comment: Yes, if the derivative of $A$ is zero, then the function $A$ is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A geometric approach:  Letting $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be the rows of $A$, we see that they are vectors on the unit circle with center $(0,0,1)$ on the plane $z = 1$.  Changing the angles by $\theta$ is a rotation in this plane, which does not change the volume of the parallelepiped determined by $v_1,v_2, v_3$.

If you want to make this rigorous, observe that

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin\left(\theta+\alpha\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\alpha\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\theta+\beta\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\beta\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\theta+\gamma\right) & \cos\left(\theta+\gamma\right) & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin\left(\alpha\right) & \cos\left(\alpha\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\beta\right) & \cos\left(\beta\right) & 1\\
\sin\left(\gamma\right) & \cos\left(\gamma\right) & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\left(\theta\right) & -\sin\left(\theta\right) & 0\\
\sin\left(\theta\right) & \cos\left(\theta\right) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

and use $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det (B)$.

(See also Blue's comment above that beat me to the punch.)

Comment: -sin(theta) should be a21 not a12 rest is fine

Comment: Interesting approach. One minor remark: "vectors on the unit circle" is not entirely clear, though in the context I understand what you mean (here there are both the affine space $\Bbb R^3$ with a plane $z=1$, and the vector space $\Bbb R^3$ with the row vectors of this $3\times3$ matrix, but of course there is a relationship between the two spaces).

Comment: @BLuthra It looks correct to me.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sure, perhaps "points on the unit circle on the plane $z = 1$" would more clear, since as vectors they are not parallel to the $z=1$ plane.

Comment: this is a determinant so we will multiply row  by row multiply sin(x)*cos(y)-cosx*siny if alpha =x and theta = y will give sin(x-y)but we want sin(x+y)

Comment: @BLuthra In matrix multiplication you multiply row by column, not row by row.

Comment: it's a determinant not a matrix

Comment: No, they are matrices in the displayed equation (they have round parentheses.)  If you take determinants everywhere than it makes no difference since the determinant of the transpose is the same as the determinant of the original.

Answer (score 4):

Expand along the last column (using [Laplace's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace's_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix)).

One [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) is for instance

$$\sin(\theta+\beta)\cos(\theta+\gamma)-\sin(\theta+\gamma)\cos(\theta+\beta)\\=
\sin[(\theta+\beta)-(\theta+\gamma)]\\=
\sin(\beta-\gamma)$$

The other two minors are similar. All in all you get:

$$|A|=\sin(\beta-\gamma)-\sin(\alpha-\gamma)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)$$

Comment: What's the the advantage? Nothing get cancel

Comment: @BLuthra $\theta$ gets canceled, with almost no calculation (you just have to know the formula for $\sin(a-b)$). But that's right, you could have found that by your method, or even by Sarrus' rule, however with some more computations. Here the minors are pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: If $A =\det (c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)$, where $c_k$ are columns (of functions with $\theta$ as argument), then a general fact is that  (product/sum rules) $$A' = \det (c_1',c_2,\cdots,c_n)+ \det (c_1, c_2',\cdots, c_n) + \cdots + \det (c_1, c_2,\cdots, c_n').$$ 
In the case here, each of the summands will be visibly zero. Hence $A'(\theta) = 0$, and $A$ does not depend on $\theta$.